# Windows Workflow 4.0 & implementing activity timeouts

Tags: .net, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I have a scenario whereby we need an activity to have a timeout associated with it so that if the activity doesn't complete within a defined period then we move on to a different activity.

How would i go about implementing this with Windows Workflow 4.0?  Clearly a parallel activity doesn't give me what we want?

e.g. If i had an activity which was prompting the user for input i would want the workflow to not wait for that user input anymore if the timeout occurs.

Apologies if i am asking a stupid question but the documentation isn't too clear given the changes between 3.0 and 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Pick activity is your friend here. Add two PickBrach activities and add the user action to one the the trigger blocks and a Delay with the timeout set in the Duration to the other Trigger. Only the Action block for the first trigger to complete will be executed.